# bootstrapping a kpathsea-like package -- finding TEXMF roots

Tags: texmf, kpathsea, engine, texmf.cnf

I am in the process of writing a Go-based TeX engine.
(it's working well and I should have a first version based off the `tex.web -> Pascal -> Go` pipeline (with DVI output) ready shortly. `TRIP` test is green).

To get that engine interoperate well with an already installed TeX distribution, I need to provide a way to locate TeX related files (I can't use `kpathsea` because of its license that doesn't play well with Go linking strategy.)

So I need to somehow find, then hook into a TDS[1](http://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf) tree.
According to [1](http://tug.org/tds/tds.pdf) and after reading the `Kpathsea` documentation[2](https://texdoc.org/serve/kpathsea/0), it seems to me the bootstrapping mechanism is the following:

- (somehow) point `kpathsea` at `<ROOT>/texmf.cnf`
- parse `texmf.cnf` and retrieve all `texmf` (TDS) root directories
- possibly look up for `ls-R` databases (from TDS roots and/or from `TEXMFDBS`).

1. is my understanding correct?
2. is there an official, standardized, way to retrieve the bootstrapping `texmf.cnf` location? *ie:* is there a recommanded environment variable pointing to it (or allowing to override it) or a set of locations one could look for in turn (and I guess those locations would be OS-dependent)?
3. or is the only way to find these locations is through invoking `kpsewhich` ?

for my distro (ArchLinux), it seems the "main" `texmf.cnf` file lives under `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` and the system-wide TDS under `/usr/share/texmf-dist`.
what would be the way to bootstrap "my" `kpath` package to locate these? (and on other OSes).
(finding user-local TDS seems easier: `TEXMFHOME`, `~/texmf` or `%USERPROFILE%/texmf`)

thanks for your time.

Comment: imho kpathsea finds the first by looking into a fix path relative to its own location. There is environment variable TEXMFCNF too, but users are not required to set it.

Comment: You might look at ConTeXt, as it doesn't use `kpathsea` but rather does it's own thing in Lua

Comment: Not directly related to your question but will you include the additional primitives from etex and pdftex? latex requires most of these to run, not just a pure tex.web engine, see  `texdoc ltnews` issue 31 "LaTeX requirements on engine primitives"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks. this boils down to either locating the kpathsea binaries or just invoking them with the correct arguments to find out where the root(s) are. ok, why not :)

Comment: @JosephWright thanks. I am looking into ConTeXt. it seems they are using their own TDS though. (but I'll dig further, thanks again)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, the plan is to be able to easily create LaTeX equations for the [Gonum](https://gonum.org) plot package. (my initial attempt, via [go-latex](https://github.com/go-latex/latex) was to implement by hand a subset of the TeX/LaTeX macros, but that proved a bit finnicky, so I switched gears). Thanks for the additional pointer.